# QPushButton tooltips inserts a line break without me specifying it

Tags: c++, qt

I have code like this:

```
//QPushButton*
myButton->setToolTip("ReallyLong String lolol<br>shortString");
```

And what happens is that sometimes, when I have a long and a short string, the long string gets cut off at some point and continues on the next line,so I end up with 3 lines, something like this:

> ReallyLong String 
> lolol 
> shortString

Why is this happening? There doesn't seem to be a way to control it.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is this happening? There doesn't seem to be a way to control it.

From the [QToolTip man page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtooltip.html):

> Rich text displayed in a tool tip is implicitly word-wrapped unless
>   specified differently with <p style='white-space:pre'>.